# Is there a way to link unconnected white spaces on my map?

Tags: python, pygame, perlin-noise

I'm using the Perlin-noise library in python to try and create procedurally generated map. I have made it so that at certain levels, there are black blocks, and at other levels there are white blocks. I want it so that my player will be able to walk on the white blocks but collide with the black blocks (but that will come later, hopefully). The problem is, sometimes the white areas are detached from each other [such as in this example (the green square is the player)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOsBh.png). What I want is that some kind of path is made through the black blocks in order for the player to be able to reach the white areas. Here is my code:

```
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
import pygame

pygame.init()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
SCREENWIDTH = 800
SCREENHEIGHT = 800

###################################################################################


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, x, y):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 4])  # create a surface to draw onto
        self.image.fill(colour)  # Set a fill colour, as the R,G,B are in equal proportion this will be a grey
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x * 4
        self.rect.y = y * 4


####################################################################################


noise1 = PerlinNoise(octaves=4)
noise2 = PerlinNoise(octaves=8)
noise3 = PerlinNoise(octaves=16)
noise4 = PerlinNoise(octaves=32)

xpix, ypix = 250, 250
pic = []
for i in range(xpix):
    row = []
    for j in range(ypix):
        noise_val = noise1([i/xpix, j/ypix])
        noise_val += 0.5 * noise2([i/xpix, j/ypix])
        noise_val += 0.25 * noise3([i/xpix, j/ypix])
        noise_val += 0.125 * noise4([i/xpix, j/ypix])

        row.append(noise_val)
    pic.append(row)

#################################################################################

size = (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((size))
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

y = 0
for row in pic:
    x = 0
    for col in row:
        if -0.1 > pic[y][x]:
            b = Block(BLACK, x, y)
        else:
            b = Block(WHITE, x, y)
        block_group.add(b)
        x += 1
    y += 1

###################################################################

carryOn = True
while carryOn:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False


    block_group.draw(screen)
    p.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYOG8kH2tF8&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eZgMK_DT5_biRkWXftAOf9&index=5) tutorial (from ep5 to ep8) could help you (he uses a marching square algorithm to display his map but the principle is the same as you). The general idea is to detect the isolated zones, then find the points that need to be connected in order to connect two zones (for each zone, the nearest point to the other zone) and finally draw the connection. You can see the final result at the end of the ep8 to see if it looks like what you want to do.